# Consider $n, k ∈ \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $\gcd(n, n + k)\mid k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

> > Consider $n, k\in\mathbb N$. Prove that $\gcd(n, n + k)\mid k$

Here is my proof. Is it correct?

A proposition in number theory states the following:

> $$\forall a, b \in \mathbb{Z}, \ \gcd(n,m)\mid an+bm$$

A corollary (consequence) to this is that if $an+bm=1$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $\gcd(n,m)=1$.

Again in our problem $(n+k)-n=k$, therefore we can use this to see that $\gcd(n,n+k)=k$.

Comment: We don't need the corollary, Directly $\, (n+k,n)\,$ divides $\,n+k\,$ and $\,n\,$ so also their diifference $= k\ \ $

Answer (score 3):

I would do it simpler. We know that $\gcd(n, n+k) | n$ and $\gcd(n, n+k)|(n+k)$. From that, it is pretty clear that $\frac{n+k}{\gcd(n, n+k)} = \frac{n}{\gcd(n, n+k)} + \frac{k}{\gcd(n, n+k)}$. The left side is an integer by definition. $\frac{n}{gcd(n, n+k)}$ is also an integer by definition. Therefore, $\frac{k}{\gcd(n, n+k)}$ is also an integer. Result follows.

Answer (score 3):

Even easier $d=\gcd(n,n+k)$

- if $d=1$ then $d \mid k$
- if $d>1$ then $d \mid n$ and $d \mid n+k$ or $d\cdot q_1=n$ and $d\cdot q_2=n+k$. Altogether $d\cdot q_2 = d\cdot q_1 +k$ or $d(q_1-q_2)=k \Rightarrow d \mid k$

Comment: You do not need to split into cases. Simply, $d\mid n $ and $d\mid (n+k)$ so $d\mid ((n+k)-n) $.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I know, it's also stated in the comments so I had to provide something different, to not be accused of plagiarism

Comment: Well, unfortunately what you wrote is not easier, and the presentation suffers from the noise of splitting into cases.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof:** Let $m=gcd(n,n+k)$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $m \mid n$ and $m \mid (n+k)$ and so $n=mx$ and $(n+k)=my$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$. Observe that $(n+k)-n=k=my-mx=m(y-x)$. Since $y-x$ is an integer, $m \mid k$. Thus, $gcd(n,n+k) \mid k$.

Answer (score 0):

We want to show that $\gcd (a, a + k) | k$

Let $\gcd (a, a + k) = d$ say, where $d$ is an integer

$d| a     \implies  a     = md$    , $m$ is an integer

$d| a + k  \implies  a + k = nd$ , $n$ is an integer

$a + k - a = nd - md $

$k = d (n - m)$

$\implies d | k$

$\implies \gcd(a,a + k) | k$    [as required]

Comment: What does RTP mean?

Comment: Hi Kien. We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Comment: RTP = 'Required To Prove'

Comment: @KienLE Almost nobody will guess that. It's better not to use abstruse abbreviations anyhow.